# Serializing an ArrayList with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

ı am working on a small c# project at visual studio 2010 and ı was trying to serialize an arraylist which has my object of People class. here is my code block

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("fs.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList));
xml.Serialize(fs,this.array);
```

and I have an error message at last line that is "There was an error generating the XML document." can anyone help me put please?

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with `this.array`.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` at all, use a `List<People>`. An `ArrayList` would only be needed if you are stuck using framework 1.x, and Visual Studio 2010 can't even target framework 1.x...

Comment: What's the type of `this.array`, and what does it contain?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using an `ArrayList` and the XmlSerializer doesn't know about your `Person` class. One possibility is to indicate to the serializer as a known type when instantiating the serializer:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList), new Type[] { typeof(Person) });
```

but a better way is to use a generic `List<T>` instead of ArrayList. So let's suppose that you have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could have a list of people:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });
people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John 2", LastName = "Smith 2" });
```

that you could serialize:

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("fs.xml"))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, people);
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using ArrayList becouse i am writting a COM Interop DLL. Is there another solution that uses ArrayList and dont required to pass the type for the Serializer constructor?